# Can you tell me if Ubuntu 12.04 LTS will work with my system?

Tags: 12.04, system, system-requirements

My computer's specification is:

- 5 GB Ram DDR1
- Video card is ATI Radeon 1 gb
- The CPU is Intel Pentium 4 Dual Core 3,0GHZ
- The operating system is Windows 7 ultimate 32bit

  Can you tell me if this will work please?

Comment: Please try this page https://friendly.ubuntu.com/ to see if your system is well supported

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS will most *definitely* work on any system which can run Windows 7!

Comment: I would only add that there are known issues with some older ATI/AMD series 4xxx cards.

Answer (score 3):

just try to boot on an ubuntu cd or usb key to test without installing !

Answer (score 1):

My PC Specs are Intel P4 HT 3.06Ghz LGA 1MB cache,1GB ddr1 ram (512+512), nVidia Geforce 6200 128mb VGA,ASUS P5Pe-vm Motherboard. this PC is Old..but ubuntu 12.04 Runs Great on it....If you are not sure about your PC...just boot your PC using a **Live CD** or a **Live Usb**